# Resume all fragments at once in viewpager/viewpager2 on calling onResume() method

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

When we override `onResume()` method in any fragment of a `viewpager`, we notice that it is actually resumed only when `viewpager` is scrolled to that particular fragment page.

So, how to resume all fragments of a `viewpager` together?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? It seems strange that you'd want to 'resume' a fragment that isn't visible.

Comment: If there's any update in my fragment that i call on onResume() method. Then, when the user slides the viewpager only till half, the update wont be visible. it will be visible all of a sudden, only when user slides viewpager to that fragment completely. This makes things ugly. I dont want this to happen. Thats why i wanted all fragments onResume() at once! Any help would be appreciated. thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you using `onResume()` for that? There is a lifecycle method that is called for each fragment - `onStart()`.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning sir. I'll try it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

call setOffscreenPageLimit with a number higher than half your fragments. This will force the viewpager to create and keep all of the fragments created as you have in your adapter.

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
```

Here I assumed 2 as the total number of fragments in viewpager